# Can Azure Functions live on the same App Service as a WebAPI, for example?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I want to consolidate a collection of Azure Functions and a WebAPI on the same App Service. Can't figure out the best way to go about it and be able to manage both solutions in the portal.

Answer (score 4):

An App Service plan supports multiple resources deployed to it: Function apps, Api apps, Web apps, etc. There shouldn't be any issue doing this.

Each app deployed to a service plan will get its own uri and local storage, but will share the app service plan's capacity (e.g. if you have an S2 plan running on 3 instances, all of your deployed apps to that App Service plan will run on all 3 instances, utilizing the resources of the S2-based instances).

Instances of the same app share disk resources. Your different apps are isolated from each other.

Comment: Does the function app need to be deployed to the app service? It doesn't seem like there is an option to add a function app to an existing app service through the Azure portal. What if I wanted to move the function app to an existing app service using FTP, what would need to be copied over and what would need to be changed for the Function App to run there?

Comment: with visual studio i could deploy to an existing service plan, if i created the app in azure portal first and then selected the existing app as "existing plan" in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You can't run them in the same site (ie, with the same URL like mysite.azurewebsites.net). Although you could use Function Proxies to forward out part of the function url namespace to the WebAPI.  Your azure function and WebAPI would be 2 separate entities in the portal, similar to having 2 separate WebAPIs.

Comment: I'm not worried about the URL, I'm looking to make the most use out of a paid plan.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is possible.

For the function app, you need to choose "app service plan", not "consumption based".

You also need to have an app service plan which isn't on the Free or Shared tier. i.e. it has to be a minimum of B1 - no minutes/hour usage limits.